# how can I improve my LSTM code on tensorflow?

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to predict the household power consumption using LSTM. The following is a small portion of input data(total training input is about ~1M records) that I am using to train my model followed by my LSTM code using TensorFlow.  I need some help with:

(1) Verification of my model : I would like a network with 2 LSTM layers of size 512 with time_step: 10.  I think I only have 1 LSTM hidden layer, but I am not sure how to add another.

(2) General improvement on my model : seems like the accuracy is not converging to any specific value and I am not quite sure where to look at this point.  Any advice on modeling/stacking layers/choice of optimizer/etc will be much appreciated.

Input data (:

```
16/12/2006;17:24:00;4.216;0.418;234.840;18.400;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2006;17:25:00;5.360;0.436;233.630;23.000;0.000;1.000;16.000
16/12/2006;17:26:00;5.374;0.498;233.290;23.000;0.000;2.000;17.000
16/12/2006;17:27:00;5.388;0.502;233.740;23.000;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2006;17:28:00;3.666;0.528;235.680;15.800;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2006;17:29:00;3.520;0.522;235.020;15.000;0.000;2.000;17.000
16/12/2006;17:30:00;3.702;0.520;235.090;15.800;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2006;17:31:00;3.700;0.520;235.220;15.800;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2006;17:32:00;3.668;0.510;233.990;15.800;0.000;1.000;17.000
16/12/2006;17:33:00;3.662;0.510;233.860;15.800;0.000;2.000;16.000
```

LSTM code :

```
from getdata_new import DataFromFile
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime


# ==========
#   MODEL
# ==========

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
training_iters = 100000
batch_size = 1000
display_step = 10

# Network Parameters
seq_len = 10 # Sequence length
n_hidden = 512 # hidden layer num of features
n_classes = 1201 #
n_input = 13
num_layers = 2

trainset= DataFromFile(filename="/tmp/train_data.txt",delim=";")

# Define weights
weights = {
      'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
      'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, seq_len, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])

def RNN(x, weights, biases):
      x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
      x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n_input])
      x = tf.split(0, seq_len, x)

      lstm_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden)

      outputs, states = tf.nn.rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

      # Linear activation, using outputs computed above
      return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']


pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer =     tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Evaluate model
correct_pred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred,1), tf.argmax(y,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_pred, tf.float32))

#test
testPred = tf.argmax(pred,1)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    acc = 0.0
    for step in range(1,training_iters+1):
        batch_x, batch_y = trainset.train_next(batch_size,seq_len)

        # Run optimization op (backprop)
        sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
        if step % display_step == 0:
            # Calculate batch accuracy
            acc = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            # Calculate batch loss
            loss = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
            print "Iter " + str(step) + ", Minibatch Loss= " + \
                  "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.5f}".format(acc)
    print "Optimization Finished!"
```

Result :

```
Iter 99860, Minibatch Loss= 0.015933, Training Accuracy= 0.29900
Iter 99870, Minibatch Loss= 0.015993, Training Accuracy= 0.26200
Iter 99880, Minibatch Loss= 0.015783, Training Accuracy= 0.30500
Iter 99890, Minibatch Loss= 0.016071, Training Accuracy= 0.27200
Iter 99900, Minibatch Loss= 0.015390, Training Accuracy= 0.40300
Iter 99910, Minibatch Loss= 0.015247, Training Accuracy= 0.43700
Iter 99920, Minibatch Loss= 0.015264, Training Accuracy= 0.42700
Iter 99930, Minibatch Loss= 0.015212, Training Accuracy= 0.43800
Iter 99940, Minibatch Loss= 0.016164, Training Accuracy= 0.26500
Iter 99950, Minibatch Loss= 0.015923, Training Accuracy= 0.30800
Iter 99960, Minibatch Loss= 0.016338, Training Accuracy= 0.22600
Iter 99970, Minibatch Loss= 0.016327, Training Accuracy= 0.19000
Iter 99980, Minibatch Loss= 0.016322, Training Accuracy= 0.22300
Iter 99990, Minibatch Loss= 0.016608, Training Accuracy= 0.15400
Iter 100000, Minibatch Loss= 0.016809, Training Accuracy= 0.10700
Optimization Finished!
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following code which I have written for Multilayer Perceptron (2 hidden layers) in Tensorflow.

Declare Weights and biases for each layer.

```
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1],stddev=0.1)), #weights for units in first hidden layer
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2],stddev=0.1)),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes],stddev=0.1)) #weights for output layer ##Check n_hidden2
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[n_hidden_1])),#biases of units of hidden layer
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[n_classes])) #biases of units of output layer
}



def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):

# Hidden layers with ELU activation
layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1']])
layer_1 = tf.nn.elu(layer_1) #Activation function for layer 1 units

layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
layer_2 = tf.nn.elu(layer_2) #Activation function for layer 2 units
out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
return tf.sigmoid(out_layer)
```

In your case,

n_hidden_1=512

n_hidden_2=512

Comment: I was trying to run changed code using your advice. but I got this error : error line >> layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1']) error msg >> ValueError: Shape (?, 10, 13) must have rank 2 which part of code should I change?

Comment: Import numpy as np then try np.array() to change shape

Comment: but Is it LSTM model? how can I input Sequence data??

Comment: I think batch_size and sequence length will define which part of the input data to be processed. Input x, in this case is just source of the data. correct me if I'm wrong